# Translucent/transparent activity in Android Wear Lollipop

Tags: android, wear-os

I had translucent activity backgrounds working on Android Wear 4.4W, by not specifying a theme, and setting the background in the activity layout to #BB000000.

Now I have Android Wear 5.0.1, the background is not translucent, and weird effects occur with elements of the foreground appearing in random places in the background, and jumping around - completely messed up.

I've tried to use a custom theme as follows:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

I also tried using

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Both with no luck - the same weird opaque effects.

My activity layout is as follows:

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:background="#BB000000"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent">

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       app:layout_box="left|bottom|right">

       <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
           android:id="@+id/wearable_list"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_width="match_parent">
       </android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView>
      </FrameLayout>
</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Where did you set the theme?

Comment: @Lukas AndroidManifest Activity definition (not Application)

Comment: Do you provide multiple values folders regarding to api level in this manner : values-v21 ?

Comment: @throws_exceptions_at_you No I don't

Comment: was there any resolution for this?

Comment: @Warlax Not that I'm aware of. I haven't tried in Android Wear 5.0.2 to see if anything is fixed though...

Answer (score 0):

Just tested in Android Wear 5.1.1

```
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

now gives a translucent background.